# "history" Module is not listed in package.json dependencies

Tags: webstorm

In the Jest tests for my React app in WebStorm, the following line

```js
const { createMemoryHistory } = require("history");
```

has the following warning:

> Module is not listed in package.json dependencies

The tests run as expected, they pass and fail as expected. `createMemoryHistory` works. And when I hover on `history` WebStorm actually shows me the documentation for the library.

(strike this:) But `history` is a native JS library, like `fs`, is it not? How do I fix this pesky warning?

**UPDATE:** Okay, I understand that `fs` is not a native JS library, it's a core node.js module. I was wrong and thanks for setting me straight on that.

I see that my `package-lock.json` does include an entry for `"node_modules/history"`. It looks like it's two indents deep, but the lockfile is too complex for me to really tell, or get breadcrumbs, or fold the branch to see where this line falls in the tree.

So I guess the real question is, Webstorm is saying that I don't have the dependency, but the lockfile implies that I do. Unless I'm misunderstanding further.

Again, how do I fix this pesky warning? (or what other fact am I missing? Remember, everything does actually *work*).

Comment: `fs` is not a "native JS library" - insofar as it isn't built-in to ECMAScript, nor is it available in web-browsers.

Comment: In NodeJS, the `require()` function is only available in server-side contexts, where `window.history` is unavailable (as the code does not run within a web-browser), so what you're trying to do is impossible.

Answer (score 1):

`fs` is a [core Node.js module](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#core-modules), i.e. its code is compiled into Node.js binary and doesn't have to be installed. [history library](https://github.com/remix-run/history) is a usual NPM module that is not a part of Node.js core and has to be added with `npm i history`(see https://github.com/remix-run/history/blob/main/docs/installation.md). The IDE just tells you that you are importing a module that is not listed among dependencies in your `package.json`

Comment: I had added `history` in that way in the past and it actually broke my application...